# Update webform without composer

Tags: webforms, composer

I need to update webform from 8.x-5.0-beta18 to 8.x-5.1  but unfortunately, I cannot use Composer because it is not possible to install it on my server due to server restrictions.

This also apply to:

- Clientside Validation 8.x-1.0-rc3 to 8.x-1.0
- Poll  8.x-1.1 to 8.x-1.2
- SMTP Authentication Support   8.x-1.0-beta3 to 8.x-1.0-beta4

as they all appear in the admin/reports/updates/update

Is there anyway to do it manually?

Comment: Sure, just do Composer on your local copy of the machine and then upload the build (the resulting files).

Comment: Unfortunately the machine has not an Internet connection as it's only used on the Intranet. Therefore when I try to install Composer it just does not work.

Comment: No internet? Well, then there's no way, no matter what you try.

Comment: Thank you so much. That explains it all. 
The machine is only accessible through the Intranet and XAMP and Drupal are installed using a local Admin account but with no access to the Internet.
I was able to install everything locally, even upgrading the Drupal core itself.
Thanks again.

Comment: Ah yeah, but that's what I meant. You do this locally on your local machine. Composer and everything. And the upload the resulting (or updated) files to the intranet Drupal.

Comment: But when I try to install composer it does not work at all. A message regarding an invalid certificate does prevent the installation.

Comment: Where? Locally on your local machine? Well, that's another issue then. Please ask a new question if you don't find any existing solutions.

Comment: The 'invalid certificate' composer error is a frustrating one but if you Google the error message, you should be able to get some help.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing any updates, make sure that you've backed up your production site to avoid loss of data. Also make sure that you have an easy way to restore the backups (:

### Solution 1

You can replicate the site on your local dev environment. Then, apply the updates using composer and upload the relevant files to the prod site.

### Solution 2

You can use `drush up MODULENAME` to update specific modules. However, make sure you've tested the updates on a dev site. However, some modules have dependencies which need to updated separately. It is for these dependencies that people recommend using `composer` for updating Drupal packages.

Comment: Would it be possible just to replace all the contents within the the c:/xampp/httdocs/drupal/modules/webform with the new version?
Thanks.

Comment: @HugoMM, if you update with `composer update drupal/webform` on your dev env, you will notice that the `modules/webform` is probably not the only thing that gets updated. You will need to upload all the files that change. Usually, this includes `modules/webform` and also the `vendor` directory created by composer. So, you might have to upload both of them.